# How to route to different servers and namespaces

Tags: nginx, url, routes, url-routing, reverse-proxy

Please forgive me if this is a bit of a punt in the dark, my DevOps/architecture skills are v v minimal so I'm not really sure on the right terminology.

I have a react app hosted on AWS which I want to sit on the root `mysite.com` as well as certain 'subdirectories' e.g`mysite.com/items` and `mysite.com/category`.

In addition, I want to have a blog hosted elsewhere but accessible at `mysite.com/blog` and some miscellaneous static pages such as `mysite.com/about` , `mysite.com/contact`. I would like those static pages to be hosted in the same place (I'm thinking webflow).

This seems like a bit of a complex setup but I'm wondering what would be the best solution. would a reverse proxy with Nginx work, if so how would you configure it? Are there other 'serverless' solutions that might work?

Perhaps there is a way to send all traffic to the static pages server unless it is the rooot or the speciic `/items` or `/category` or `/blog` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi a basic configuration could look like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    return 200 "Blog \n";
}

server {
    listen 8081;
    return 200 "About and Contact \n";
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location = /about {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    }

    location  /blog {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Let me add some text to it :)

if you just want to have a location /about without anything more in the location you can use `= /about`

trying to add something behind `/about` like `/about/foo` will result in a 404.

If you want to proxy the blog to some other location use `/blog`. With this configuration you are free to add somethin to your location like `/blog/test/` and it will still response with a 200.

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# curl -v localhost/blog/test
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /blog/test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.6
< Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2020 06:09:31 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 12
< Connection: keep-alive
<
/blog/test
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

#### The serverless way in development

is using something in your react app to route the traffic to the right target.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually

I did this for one of my projects and its workig great!

I will share my file without adapting it to your question just as a general reference and idea.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/api', proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
    }));

    app.use('/img', proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
    }));

    app.use('/oauth', proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
    }));
};
```

This file (setupProxy.js) lives inside of thr src directory on the root level.

## For production

I just know about some integration with express ontop of node.js. As proxying is deeply releated to the http-protocoll you devenetly need a some server component understanding the http protocol.

I have noticed a couple of disadvantages during the last months using an express webserver as proxy. Caching is more effective on the NGINX level. If the routing-complexty increases the NGINX can deal a lot better with it.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed reply and the different options shown. I hadn't thought about doing the routing directly in the react app that is an interesting option! With the NGINX version, you talk about being able to use `/blog/somethingelse` was the `.` supposed to be part of the location? so `location /blog. {` ?

Comment: No. It's like in my configuration listed above. Without a `.` .

Comment: ok perfect so it's all about the `=`.  The part that is confusing me though is how i tell it to use the S3 bucket for the root and the other parts of the react app?

Comment: would something like this work? `server {
    listen 8080;
    return 200 "Blog \n";
}

server {
    listen 8081;
    return 200 "About and Contact static pages \n";
}

server {
    listen 8082;
    return 200 "React app \n";
}

`

Comment: `server {
    listen 80;

    location = /about {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/contact;
    }

    location = /about {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/about;
    }

    location  /blog {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
    }
    
    location /items {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/items;
    }

    location /category {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/category;
    }
}`

Comment: All right. Can you use ReactRouter to craete your static pages /item, /about and /contact with react? In that case you would need on server location / pointing to react app. For your blog create another location /blog and proxy the traffic to your blog. Thats bascially it. That how I would do? Whats the S3 thing? Are your react app files are stored in a S3 bucket? Is it public available or private in case the answer is yes.